# Function to support addition & subtraction of both numbers & date

Tags: postgresql

Need of a generic Postgres function to support addition & subtraction of both number & date (timestamp without time zone).

It's expected to support number + number, date + number, date - number like formats. Type need be identified at runtime if possible. Is it feasible?

Comment: `date+date` makes no sense. What is the expected result of `"March, 12th 2020" + "February 2nd, 1987"` But all the other calculations are already supported out of the box, why do you want a function for that?

Comment: Corrected that point. Thanks. 
Trying an Oracle to Postgre migration. Here hql queries are generated dynamically with a for loop in java, where these additions & subtractions will come & supported in Oracle. But postgre throwing errors like
"function to_number(interval) does not exist", "operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone + numeric" etc

Comment: Well, `number + number` or `date + number` already works in Postgres. `to_number(interval)` doesn't exist in Oracle either

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL has a number of operators for date arithmetic. To name the most important options for addition:

- `date + integer → date`
- `date + time without time zone → timestamp without time zone`
- `date + interval → timestamp with time zone`
- `timestamp without time zone + interval → timestamp without time zone`
- `timestamp with time zone + interval → timestamp without time zone`

Subtraction works similar.

Multiplication and division exist for `interval` and `double precision`.

That works quite the same as in Oracle, so code should not be hard to port.

Some differences:

- While Oracle's `timestamp with time zone` stores the time zone information along with the data, PostgreSQL doesn't. Rather, it converts the timestamp to UTC before storing it, and upon display, it is converted to the `timezone` setting active in the database connection.
- Oracle's `date` (strangely) has fields for hour to second and is best translated to `timestamp(0) without time stamp`.
- Oracle has two `interval` data types, but they both can be represented as PostgreSQL's `interval`.
- Oracle does not have an `integer` data type, so you have to translate Oracle's `number` to `integer` for PostgreSQL. This might present a problem if you add numbers with a fraction – that would have to be translated to `timestamp + interval`.
- Replace the Oracle-specific `sysdate` with `clock_timestamp()`.